# changing src of a main div on hovering on another divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, imagesource

```
<html>
<head><script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<div><img src="images/img-40.jpg" class="Main-image"/></div>

<div id="iranimg"><img src="images/irani.jpg" style="display:none;"/>Iran </div>
<div id="spainimg"><img src="images/spanin.jpg" style="display:none;"/>Spain </div>
<div id="turkeyimg"><img src="images/turkey.jpg" style="display:none;"/>Turkey </div>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#iranimg').hover(function() {
$( '.Main-image' ).attr("src","images/irani.jpg");
}, function() {
    $( '.Main-image' ).attr("src","images/img-40.jpg");

});


})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to change `src of 'main-image' div with a`src of a another divs only when hover on that divs.

When I hover on that div it replaces with the specific `src`.

I want to dynamically get `src` of each div and replace it with `src` of main div image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `src` of inner `img` tag when hovering and replace with that

```
$('#iranimg,#spainimg,#turkeyimg').hover(function() {
  $('.Main-image').attr("src", $('img',this).attr('src'));
}, function() {
  $('.Main-image').attr("src", "images/img-40.jpg");
});
```

---

**FYI :** Use `class` instead of `id`, so you can make it more simple

**jQuery:**

```
$('.imgChange').hover(function() {
  $('.Main-image').attr("src", $('img',this).attr('src'));
}, function() {
  $('.Main-image').attr("src", "images/img-40.jpg");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div><img src="images/img-40.jpg" class="Main-image"/></div>

<div class="imgChange"><img src="images/irani.jpg" style="display:none;"/>Iran </div>
<div class="imgChange"><img src="images/spanin.jpg" style="display:none;"/>Spain </div>
<div class="imgChange"><img src="images/turkey.jpg" style="display:none;"/>Turkey </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   $('div[id$="img"]').hover(function() {
    $( '.Main-image' ).attr("src",$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    }, function() {
    $( '.Main-image' ).attr("src","images/img-40.jpg");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

You can keep the images if you had them to preload, but use the data attribute and a class to add the event to all divs

```js
$(function() {
  $('.countries').hover(function() {
    $('.Main-image').attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
  }, function() {
    $('.Main-image').attr("src", "images/img-40.jpg");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="images/img-40.jpg" class="Main-image" />
</div>

<div class="countries" id="iranimg" data-src="images/irani.jpg">Iran</div>
<div class="countries" id="spainimg" data-src="images/spanin.jpg">Spain</div>
<div class="countries" id="turkeyimg" data-src="images/turkey.jpg">Turkey</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#iranimg').hover(function() {
    $('.Main-image').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
 }, function() {
    $('.Main-image').attr('src', "images/img-40.jpg");
 });
```